# Performance testing tool for web-pages

Tags: performance, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web

Im looking for simplest way to masure how much time a web page loads ( sharepoint 2010 ) 
If passible with windows tool

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in debugging tool that ships with IE to get some basic metrics on the performance of your page.  In IE, hit F12 to open the debugger, then switch to the "Profiler" tab.

Comment: From the profiler tab, you can start profiling.  It will collect data while you browse and use the site (in this case Sharepoint).  When finished, just click stop in the profiler and it will give you a nice result

Answer (score 1):

The Developer Dashboard is the perfect tool for this, it will show times between SQL and pages, highlighting where all steps occur not just from the page serve.

[MSDN Article about the Developer Dashboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512745.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following PowerShell script to enable Dev Dashboard. It will give you ALL the timings on your pages.

```
$spDevDash = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService.DeveloperDashboardSettings;
$spDevDash.DisplayLevel = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDeveloperDashboardLevel]::OnDemand;
$spDevDash.RequiredPermissions = ‘EmptyMask’;
$spDevDash.TraceEnabled = $true;
$spDevDash.Update();
```

@Paul yeah this tool is perfect for this.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers have some sort of profiling tool built in.
My favorite by far is the YSlow extension for firefox (requires the firebug extension) https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/

It gives you a grade (A-F) rating on each of the components on your page (number of httpRequests, headers, links, redirects, css usage etc).
With each of the grades it presents tips for optimization, e.g. minifying css and js files, adding expires-headers etc, with thorough descriptions on how to do the actual optimization.

It also gives you a nice breakdown of the size of each file that gets loaded (images, js, css files) with some pie charts that show the weight of each component on your page, helping you get a good view of your page footprint.